# Left arrow key doesn't work after laptop water spill

Tags: laptop-repair, water-damage

Today I accidentally spilled a small amount of water on my laptop, Samsung RC-720. I immediately went into panic mode, put laptop upside down and wiped all the water.

The laptop didn't shut down, everything was ok, so, I thought thanks to this model's keyboard...

[image: keyboard]

...I'm safe. But now I discovered that my left arrow button isn't working! This isn't a very big deal, but as a coder I regret this very much. It is especially weird because I spilled water somewhere in the numpad area, but only one button far from there died =(.

What can I do now by myself? And if not, may be I can somehow map FN button to work as left arrow button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hair dryer, run cold or warm (not hot) air for 5 minutes. After a day or two, it should be fine if it was water. I had coffee spilled and it was ok since I cleaned quickly.

Comment: It took one weeek to dry my ThinkPad's keyboard. Patience.

Comment: Thanks! Is it important not to use the laptop while waiting for the water to vaporise?

Comment: It is VERY important, yes. Don't use it at all.